# How can I initialize a Doubly Linked List only once even if I run the program multiple times?

Tags: c, ubuntu

I have a doubly linked list that stores names, which I can add/remove names from it, show them, etc., by running the program multiple times (according to the parameter I wrote in the terminal).

The first time I run the program (let's say to add a name since there are none to remove or show), it creates the doubly linked list and it initializes it with size=0 and rear=front=NULL.

My main problem is that, when I run the program a second time, it creates a new doubly linked list, losing the pointer to the previously-created list and, naturally, losing the first name added to the list.

Is there any way to let my program know that there is already a list created and channel the pointer of the list to it after I run it the second, third, fourth, etc., time and using that list for the next action?

I don't think adding the code is necessary but, in case it's needed, let me know to update my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data must be persistent in external storage for program to read and write.
By calling it external, we refer to disk, not memory space designated to the process.
You could have the program to open file and keep record of the any structured data. When the program runs again it probe to create the next node of name.

Comment: So there is no way to keep the number of files to one(main.c)?

Comment: No, not in-memory, if double-linked list is created by the very first process followed by the next launch trial.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the ubuntu tag, you can use POSIX named shared memory to achieve it: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html . You could need some pointer tricks to make it work.

However, for your persistence use case I would go with storing them in a file, in a tmpfs if you don't want to touch the disk. You would need the same pointer tricks as the POSIX shared memory, with more portability and it's much easier to reason about it.

Answer (score -1):

You should have 2 classes, the DLList class should manage the count/size, pointer to start/end, functions to add/remove. The Node list is obivous. In the main program you create an empty DLList class to begin with.

Comment: The question asked is `C`

Comment: In C you use structs/pointers, I don;t see much difference

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it obvious but then code is written in C which doesn't include classes, unless if you mean using static globals variables and static functions.

Comment: C struct is a direct analog of classes (or other other way around), this has nothing to do with globals

Comment: "*C struct is a direct analog of classes*" -- this is a false statement. They are **very** different things. C++ does have classes (and structs), but this is a C question (which only has structs).

Comment: Also, your answer doesn't seem to address the question at all. The question is about data persistence, and your answer doesn't discuss that at all. Please read the question more carefully next time.